# Counting input from read always return 1 in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am accepting input from a user by using `read`. I am trying to count the result as usual with `wc -c`, and store it into a variable, but the result always returns 1.

Below is the

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo -n "Enter your plaintext.> "
read text

count=$(echo $text | wc -w)
echo  $count
```

Somehow when the variable is not store as variable and directly echo out will be the correct result.

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo -n "Enter your plaintext.> "
read text

echo $text | wc -w
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I tried the code in the question and It worked for me.

Comment: @andcoz it is correct if you counting the word ,but I specify a -c to count the character which isn't correct

Comment: In question text you talk of `wc -c` while in the code you use `wc -w`, which one is the correct one? What are you triyng to count? Words or characters?

Comment: Guess i got a typo error myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works.

```
read text
count=$( echo "$text" | wc -w )
```

This will set `count` to 2 if I enter the text `hello world`.

In the comments, you talk about counting characters.

```
count=$( echo "$text" | wc -c )
```

or

```
count=${#text}
```

will do that for you. However, the `wc` solution will also count the final newline, giving you a value that is one character larger than the parameter expansion method. The `wc` method will also compress spaces in the string unless you double quote the expansion of `$text` like I've done above.

Comment: Thanks for an clear answer although it is just a typo , but I expect more downvote to make this question less relevant to search in this community.